# Calculation of the value of 4-th degree polynomial using only 3 variables(C++)

Tags: c++

I want to create a programm, that computes the value of 4-th degree polynomial using only 3 variables of fundamental type  in C++.

here is my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        int i;
        double x,y = 0,coef;
        cout << "Enter please a number X:";
        cin >> x;
        for(i = 0; i <= 4; ++i)
        {
            cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number of coefficient "<< i << " power:";
            cin >> coef;
            if(i == 0){
                y += coef;
            }else{
                y += coef * pow(x,i);
            }

        }
        cout << "The result is: " << y  << "\n";
        return 0;
}
```

But I used already 4 variables. How can I create the same programm only with 3 variables? Ideally I want to use multiplication operation only 3 times

Comment: Curious about the rationale for this.

Comment: Unroll the loop and now you're only using 3 variables.

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you mean by unroll?

Comment: @soc5 unrol means = your loop is only 4 iteratiions so write 4 iterations

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I'm not getting what your problem is.

Comment: @TemaniAfif actually, my loop has 5 iterations(as it should be). But I didn't understand how it will help to solve my problem?

Comment: @user7631183 instead of 4 variables I want to use 3

Comment: @soc5 without the loop no need the variable `i`

Comment: @soc5 but what should he do with variable "coef" without loop? It will turn into 4 variables...

Comment: ***what should he do with variable "coef" without loop?*** The same thing with the loop. If you unroll you have `x`, `y` and `coef` but no `i` You also remove the if () statement completely.

Comment: @drescherjm   yes, you are right, sorry

Comment: If the OP still needs help this explains unrolling a loop: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion to solve your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double compute(int i, double x)
{
    double coef;
    cout << i + 1 << ". Enter number of coefficient "<< i << " power:";
    cin >> coef;

    if ( i == 0 )
        return coef;
    else
        return coef*pow(x, i) + compute(i - 1, x);
}

int main()
{
        double x;
        cout << "Enter please a number X:";
        cin >> x;

        cout << "The result is: " << compute(4, x) << "\n";
        return 0;
}
```

but I really don't know the rationale to do this

Comment: Each active recursion creates three new variables, so you actually made it worse. (Presumably we are trying to minimize stack usage.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Not sure what is presumably here. It seems to me that the goal is to minimize the number of declared variables.

Comment: There is no practical reason for minimizing the number of declared variables just because you don't like declaring variables. The only practical reason I can think of is that there is an assumption that a declared variable occupies stack space. (Also, parameters are declared variables, so you introduced new variables by adding a function with two parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

An iterative solution using Horner’s method:

```
double result=0, new_term=0;
while (getdouble(new_term)) result=result*x + new_term;
```

Here `bool getdouble(double &a)` is responsible of detecting end of stream *somehow*.